# Making https call in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, https, thingworx

I have to make a HTTPS call in nodejs but I am unable to make it .

I am using the below code

```
request('https://url for the service', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
     console.log(body.url);
    console.log(body.explanation);
});
```

But I am getting an error

> Connection Timeout :
>
> ip:443

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `rejectUnauthorized:false` while calling https request. Because request client will throws an error while doing SSL handshake.

```
request('https://url for the service', { json: true, rejectUnauthorized: false }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
     console.log(body.url);
    console.log(body.explanation);
});
```

Comment: Hi .. I tried this . I am getting the below response in the nodejs console.

{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ip:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'ip',
  port: 443 }

Comment: Can you able to ping the host from your shell/command line (ex.) ping https://urlto-ping. If it didnt work there's some issue in your proxy setup

Comment: Thanks for the help the issue was with the network proxy. I was able to call the api from other network